# UITableView not scrollable after scrollToRow

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a table with number of rows. I would like to pre-scroll table after it's load and it's not so hard, but I have a problem. Table become non-scrollable after `scrollToRow` execution.

Here is my code scroll function:

```
func scrollToValue() {
        var scrollPosition: Int = 30
        let indexPath = IndexPath(row: scrollPosition, section: 0)
        tableView.scrollToRow(at: indexPath, at: .middle, animated: true)
}
```

and I execute it in `viewDidLayoutSubviews`:

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        scrollToValue()
}
```

Here is what I have executed this code and try to move table top or bottom: table moves back to `15.0` value at the middle after my interaction, but I would like to scroll to any other position top and bottom without rollback. Even though if I choose **false** for animation `scrollToRow(at: indexPath, at: .middle, animated: false)` I can't move cells at all. I can see scroll indicator at the right but cells are frozen.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove scroll action from layoutSubviews as tableView is still not loaded and try this

```
override func viewDidAppear() {
    scrollToValue()
}
```